# How to Split a large parquet file to multiple parquet and save in different hadoop path by time column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, parquet, large-data

My sparquet file like this

### id, name, date

1, a, 1980-09-08

2, b, 1980-09-08

3, c, 2017-09-09

Hope the output file like this

[image]

the folder `19800908` contains data

### id, name, date

1, a, 1980-09-08

2, b, 1980-09-08

and the folder `20170909` contains data

### id, name, date

3, c, 2017-09-09

I know can groupBy key `date` but don't know how to output multiple parquet file use such class `MultipleTextOutputFormat`

I don't want to foreach loop the keys, which to slow and need a lot of memory

now the code like this

```scala
   val input = sqlContext.read.parquet(sourcePath)
      .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

    val keyRows: RDD[(Long, Row)] =
      input.mapPartitions { partition =>
        partition.flatMap { row =>
          val key =  format.format(row.getDate(3)).toLong
          Option((key, row))
        }
      }.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

    val keys = keyRows.keys.distinct().collect()

    for (key <- keys) {
      val rows = keyRows.filter { case (_key, _) => _key == key }.map(_._2)
      val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, input.schema)
      val path = s"${outputPrefix}/$key"
      HDFSUtils.deleteIfExist(path)
      df.write.parquet(path)
    }
```

If I use the MultipleTextOutputFormat the output as follows which not I want

[image]

```scala
    keyRows.groupByKey()
      .saveAsHadoopFile(conf.getOutputPrefixDirectory, classOf[String], classOf[String],
        classOf[SimpleMultipleTextOutputFormat[_, _]])
```

```java
public class SimpleMultipleTextOutputFormat<A, B> extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<A, B> {

    @Override
    protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(A key, B value, String name) {
//        return super.generateFileNameForKeyValue(key, value, name);
        return key.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this function `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile`  useful

Answer (score 1):

Writing with partitioned column can be used:

```
df.write.partitionBy("dateString").parquet("/path/to/file").
```

Difference - folder name will be like "dateString=2017-09-09", and new string column "dateString" have to be created before saving.

Comment: The source file is very big, there are 25 g. The task to run very memory which cause the error “spark.yarn.executor.memoryoverhead”

Comment: Maybe, memory issue related not to writing, but to processing. This can be checked by removing "partitionBy" from write clause.

Comment: But I need the "partitionBy" clause to partition the source file~

Answer (score 0):

from this post [spark partition data writing by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527888/spark-partition-data-writing-by-timestamp)

```scala
    input
      .withColumn("_key", date_format(col(partitionField), format.toPattern))
      .write
      .partitionBy("_key")
      .parquet(conf.getOutputPrefixDirectory)
```

[image]

But how to remove the folder name '_ke='